# Пересоздать массив исходя из оригинала, приведя его к 0

Tags: c#

Всем привет. Не уверен, как правильно назвать тему. Надеюсь, никого не сбил с толку...

У меня есть массив чисел:
1, 2, 5, 6, 8

Нужно привести эти числа к порядку:
0, 1, 2, 3, 4

Пробовал вариант с циклом и пересозданием массива в новый, но это крайне некрасиво выглядит. Есть ли более элегантное решение?

UPD:
Ещё пример:

Было: 1, 5, 10, 11, 13, 20

Стало: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Comment: Не особо понятно, какому порядку? По какой логике второй массив появился? Из первого от каждого числа отнимают 2?

Comment: Написал ещё пример, чтобы понятнее было

Comment: Вам нужно заполнить недостающие элементы?

Comment: Нужно переписать массив, чтобы он начинался с 0, с таким же количеством элементов

Comment: `int[] arr2 = Enumerable.Range(0, arr.Length).ToArray();` Возможно это то, что вам нужно

Comment: Задали бы вопрос "хочу массив той же длины, заполненный числами от 0 по порядку", а не вот это вот всё, и стало бы сразу понятно, что вам нужно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пусть Ваш массив имеет длину `X`, тогда для создания другого массива с числами от 0 до X-1 можно взять отрезок с методом [`Enumerable.Range(start, end)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=net-6.0), а затем преобразовать его в массив с помощью `ToArray()`:

```
int X = old_arr.Length; // длина старого массива
int[] new_arr = Enumerable.Range(0, X).ToArray();

// X = 5 => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```